# ReactJS: How do I keep my checkbox and radio button checked/selected on page reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my radio buttons and checkboxes from material UI and they work as expected. Data is stored is state and local storage correctly and is persisted correctly too. I have a multistep form and my issues is that, when I select the radio button or checkbox and move to the next page then come back, my selections appear "not selected", like the checkboxes are not checked and radio button selected is not filled even though they are and data is stored correctly in state and local storage persists the selections. How do I keep my selections selected and appear to the user correctly?

Here is one of the radio button pages:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Global } from "../../../shared/utilities/scripts/global.context";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";

import ArrowBackIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack";
import ArrowForwardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward";

import "./nanny.complete.profile.css";

const radioStyle = {
  color: "#9695b9",
  "&.Mui-checked": {
    color: "#9695b9",
  },
};

const Radius = () => {
  //to translate page
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const { radioSelected, setRadioSelected } = useContext(Global);
  const { values, setValues } = useContext(Global);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  //get state from localStorage to persist
  useEffect(() => {
    const localState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("values"));
    if (values.radius === "") {
      setValues((values) => ({ ...values, ...localState }));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localDisabled = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("disabled"))
    if(values.radius === "") {
      setDisabled(localDisabled)
    }else {
      setDisabled(!localDisabled)
    }
  })

  //setting localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("values", JSON.stringify(values));
  }, [values.radius]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("disabled", JSON.stringify(disabled));
  }, []);

  const handleRadio = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setRadioSelected(value);
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const controlProps = (item) => ({
    checked: radioSelected === item,
    onChange: handleRadio,
    value: item,
    name: "radius",
    inputProps: { "aria-label": item },
  });

  return (
    <div className="sub-settings-div">
      <Link className="back" to="/vaccination">
        <span>
          <ArrowBackIcon />
        </span>
        Back
      </Link>
      <h3 className="sub-settings-header">{t("common.title")}</h3>
      <h2 className="sub-settings-sub-header">{t("radius.subTitle")}</h2>
      <div className="radio-container">
        <div className="radio-item">
          <Radio
            className="radio"
            sx={radioStyle}
            {...controlProps("0-5 km")}
          />
          <div className="labels">
            <label className="label">
              0-5 km
              <p>
                {" "}
                {`(${t("radius.car")}: 5-10 mins / ${t(
                  "radius.bike"
                )}: 15-20 mins)`}
              </p>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="radio-item">
          <Radio
            className="radio"
            sx={radioStyle}
            {...controlProps("5-10 km")}
          />
          <div className="labels">
            <label className="label">
              5-10 km
              <p>
                {" "}
                {`(${t("radius.car")}: 10-20 mins / ${t(
                  "radius.bike"
                )}: 20-35 mins)`}
              </p>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="radio-item">
          <Radio
            className="radio"
            sx={radioStyle}
            {...controlProps("10-20 km")}
          />
          <div className="labels">
            <label className="label">
              10-20 km
              <p>
                {" "}
                {`(${t("radius.car")}: 20-30 mins / ${t(
                  "radius.bike"
                )}: 35-50 mins)`}
              </p>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="radio-item">
          <Radio
            className="radio"
            sx={radioStyle}
            {...controlProps("20-50 km")}
          />
          <div className="labels">
            <label className="label">
              20-50 km
              <p>
                {" "}
                {`(${t("radius.car")}: 30-60 mins > ${t("radius.recommend")})`}
              </p>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="nav-btns">
        <Link to="/vaccination" className="prev-link">
          <button className="prev">{t("buttons.back")}</button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/booked" className="next-link">
          <button disabled = {disabled ? true : false} className={disabled ? "disabled" : "next"}>
            {t("buttons.next")}
            <span>
              <ArrowForwardIcon />
            </span>
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Radius;
```

And one of the pages with checkboxes:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Global } from "../../../shared/utilities/scripts/global.context";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

import ArrowBackIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack";
import ArrowForwardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward";

import "./nanny.complete.profile.css";

const checkboxStyle = {
  color: "#9695b9",
  "&.Mui-checked": {
    color: "#9695b9",
  },
};

const AgeRange = () => {
  //to translate page
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  //state from context API
  const { values, setValues } = useContext(Global);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  //get state from localStorage to persist
  useEffect(() => {
    const localState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("values"));
    if (values.ageRange.length === 0) {
      setValues((values) => ({ ...values, ...localState }));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localDisabled = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("disabled"))
    if(values.ageRange.length === 0) {
      setDisabled(localDisabled)
      console.log(disabled)
    }else {
      setDisabled(!localDisabled)
    }
  })

  //setting localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("values", JSON.stringify(values));
  }, [values.ageRange]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("disabled", JSON.stringify(disabled));
  }, []);

  //handle checkbox selection
  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target;

    let newSelected = [...values.ageRange, id];
    if (values.ageRange.includes(id)) {
      newSelected = newSelected.filter((choice) => choice !== id);
    }

    setValues({
      ...values,
      ageRange: newSelected,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="sub-settings-div">
      <Link className="back" to="/hourly-rate">
        <span>
          <ArrowBackIcon />
        </span>
        Back
      </Link>
      <h3 className="sub-settings-header">{t("common.title")}</h3>
      <h2 className="sub-settings-sub-header">{t("ageRange.subTitle")}</h2>
      <div className="checkbox-container">
        <div className="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            className="check"
            sx={checkboxStyle}
            id="babies"
            onChange={handleSelect}
          />
          <label className="label" htmlFor="babies">
            {t("ageRange.babies")} <span>{`(0-1 ${t("ageRange.years")})`}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            className="check"
            sx={checkboxStyle}
            id="infants"
            onChange={handleSelect}
          />
          <label className="label" htmlFor="infants">
            {t("ageRange.infants")}{" "}
            <span>{`(1-3 ${t("ageRange.years")})`}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            className="check"
            sx={checkboxStyle}
            id="playschool"
            onChange={handleSelect}
          />
          <label className="label" htmlFor="playschool">
            {t("ageRange.playschool")}{" "}
            <span>{`(3-6 ${t("ageRange.years")})`}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            className="check"
            sx={checkboxStyle}
            id="mini"
            onChange={handleSelect}
          />
          <label className="label" htmlFor="mini">
            {t("ageRange.mini")} <span>{`(6-10 ${t("ageRange.years")})`}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            className="check"
            sx={checkboxStyle}
            id="maxi"
            onChange={handleSelect}
          />
          <label className="label" htmlFor="maxi">
            {t("ageRange.maxi")} <span>{`(10-14 ${t("ageRange.years")})`}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="nav-btns">
        <Link to="/hourly-rate" className="prev-link">
          <button className="prev">{t("buttons.back")}</button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/car" className="next-link">
          <button disabled = {disabled ? true : false} className={disabled ? "disabled" : "next"}>
            {t("buttons.next")}
            <span>
              <ArrowForwardIcon />
            </span>
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AgeRange;
```

Any help would truly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Method**

You can store bool value to localstorage as soon as the checkbox or radio is been selected. Get the values from localStorage and check with bool value if its true make it as checked.

```
<Checkbox
  className="check"
  sx={checkboxStyle}
  id="infants"
  onChange={handleSelect}
  checked = { values.isCheckboxSelected ? true : false}
   // you can replace isCheckboxSelected name with your own choise 
  />
```

**2. Method**
If you are using **redux** then we have library called **redux-persist** which stores all your state data to localstorage so you can easily persist all the state values.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

**Below is how i am using in one of my APP**

```
               <StyledInputField
                  name="above25Years"
                  value={checkout.above25Years}
                  onChange={(e) => dispatch(setAbove25Years(true))}
                  type="radio"
                  checked={checkout.above25Years ? true : false}
                  width={'25px'}
                  height={'25px'}
                /> Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already using react context, you already one step closer to persisting your values.

You need to do some correction to your codes

```
  //get state from localStorage to persist
  useEffect(() => {
    const localValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("values"));
    setValues(localValues)
  }, []);

  //save to localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values));
  }, [values])
```

Any values that uses setValue from your GlobalContext will be persist to your localStorage.

Since you already persisting the state in your context provider, you can **remove** the localStorage codes in your `AgeRange` component so there is only a single source of truth, else they will be overwriting each other.

Comment: Hey, I set the global context with data from the local storage so ideally there is one source of truth. Or what am I not getting right?

Comment: If you are using the values from your Global context as the checkbox/radio values, then yes, you only need to save/load localstorage at one place.